# Greying-out images?

Tags: icon, images

Could someone recommend me an easy to use tool for greying-out some images (icons) ?.
In an Android application I am doing I have a set of full color icons that I want to use in a tab bar, but I want only the icon at the selected tab to be in color, and the other ones should be shown greyed-out. Then I am looking for an easy way to generate the greyed-out icons from the color ones. 
Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

Any decent image editor will have a desaturate/convert to greyscale command or a Hue/Saturation/Value editor that lets you do this.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html).

You basically just upload your images and it generates the proper icons for you. It provides a lot of configuration options and all possible types of icons you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Octavian Damiean. Apparently Android Asset Studio now is part of the Eclipse plugin. I have been playing with it for a while trying to grey-out one image without success. Strangely enough the tool generates a picture with the same shape of my original png image, but all its content is just white. This is for the selected tab image. For the unselected tab image I have a similar situation, a picture with the same shape but all in grey. Do you know why is that and how I could fix it ?